# How to check for the presence of text in a ListView row that uses an adapter which extends BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, android-espresso

I have an Activity that contains a ListView that I am trying to test the existence of a specific entry using Espresso. The ListView's data is displayed using an Adapter that extends BaseAdapter.

```
public class CommentListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    Context context;
    List<Comment> comments;

    public CommentListAdapter(Context context, List<Comment> comments) {
        this.context = context;
        this.comments = comments;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return comments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return comments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_row, null);
        }

        TextView timestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentTimestamp);
        timestamp.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(comments.get(position).getTimeStamp()));

        TextView commentText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentText);
        commentText.setText(comments.get(position).getComment());

        return view;
    }
}
```

The field that I need to interrogate is the R.id.commentText field. Looking at the documentation for Espresso I have seen an example for a SimpleAdapter but can't see how to refactor this to work with my CommentAdapter.

I do wonder whether I should use SimpleAdapter or ArrayAdapter, however, I went down the route of extending BaseAdapter because another article recommended it. It feels wrong changing my implementation just to get an Espresso test to run because it's not obvious how to write the test code.

Please, can anyone help?

Marc

The solution I ended up going with was to use an ArrayAdapter instead of extending BaseAdapter and creating the following Matcher

```
public class CommentListAdapterMatchers {
    public static Matcher<Object> withContent(String expectedText) {
        return withContent(equalTo(expectedText));
    }

    public static Matcher<Object> withContent(final Matcher<String> expectedObject) {
        return new BoundedMatcher<Object, Comment>(Comment.class) {
            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(Comment actualObject) {
                return expectedObject.matches(actualObject.getComment());
            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with content: " + description);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Finally I used the following onData call

```
onData(allOf(is(Comment.class), CommentListAdapterMatchers.withContent("My Comment4"))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

This worked on my test project but then as soon as I integrated it into a more complex layout I needed to specify the ListView I was interested in using inAdapterView

```
onData(allOf(is(Comment.class), CommentListAdapterMatchers.withContent("My Comment4"))).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.commentListView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: You should not look for text in a TextView of an item of your listview. Instead look for this tekst in the List comments.

Comment: That helped my understanding but the main issue was around the selection and matchers definition.